# Example of a Well-Ordered Class that is not Proper

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

I am currently studying well-ordered classes in the context of [NBG set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) and I am trying to find a well-ordered class that is *not* ***proper***. Here is the relevant definition of the terminology (assuming one is already familiar with well-ordered classes):

- Given a class $A$ that is linearly ordered by $\le$, a subclass $B$ is called a ***lower section*** of $A$ *iff* all elements in $B$ are less than each element of $A$ not in $B$. We call $B$ a ***proper lower section*** if, in addition, $B \neq A$.
- We call a well-ordered class $A$ ***proper*** *iff* every proper lower section of $A$ is not only a class but also a set.

Thus, I am essentially trying to find a well-ordered class that has a proper lower section which is also a proper class. Initially, I immediately thought of the class of all ordinals $On$ but that turned out to be wrong. Right now, I am trying to construct a well-ordered class that has $On$ as a proper lower section but I am clueless as to how to do it. Could someone give me some pointers or suggest a different route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following ordering $\prec$ on $\mathrm Ord$:

$$\alpha\prec\beta\iff\begin{cases}\beta=0,\alpha>0& \text{or}\\0<\alpha<\beta\end{cases}$$

Then $0$ has a proper class of predecessors. It's not hard to see that this is indeed a well-ordered class.

Comment: I see. This is simple and clever. Just to clarify, denoting this new well-order as $On^*$, the proper lower section that is strictly a class would be $On^* \setminus \{0\}$ right?

Comment: Yes. And it is of course isomorphic to $\mathrm{Ord}$ itself.